# Encoding dates as ulong for use with AmiBroker

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, bit-manipulation

I am developing a data plugin for Amibroker using the unofficial C# sdk from http://code.google.com/p/amibroker.  What is does is read a text file, parse the contents to amibroker's database format so the data can be displayed as a graph.  Here is a sample of the input data:

2012.07.09 01:35:27,12763,1
2012.07.09 01:35:50,12762,1
2012.07.09 01:36:43,12761,1
2012.07.09 01:37:10,12760,1
2012.07.09 01:37:44,12761,1

The format being date/time, close, volume.

A sample of the output is (how the above 5 lines got parsed):

2012/07/09 01:35 12763  1
2083/08/22   12762  1
2083/08/22   12761  1
2012/07/09 01:37 12760  1
2083/08/22   12761  1

As you can see, some dates are coming out correct, others are coming out as 2083/08/22.  How is this happening, because all the input dates are in the same format?

In the c# dll, the code that I'm using for the import is:

```
unsafe public static int GetQuotesEx(string ticker, Periodicity periodicity, int lastValid, int size, Quotation* quotes, GQEContext* context)
    {

        string fileName = "C:\\" + ticker + ".txt";

        System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
        int i = 0;
        string line = "";

        while((line = objReader.ReadLine()) != null && i < size)
        {
            string[] splitLine = line.Split(',');
            DateTime   dt = Convert.ToDateTime(splitLine[0]);
            float bidprice = float.Parse(splitLine[1]);
            float volume = float.Parse(splitLine[2]);

            quotes[i].DateTime = PackDate(dt);
            quotes[i].Price = bidprice;
            quotes[i].Open = bidprice;
            quotes[i].High = bidprice;
            quotes[i].Low = bidprice;
            quotes[i].Volume = volume;
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }
```

And the PackDate function code (I didn't write this, it's in the dll):

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Pack AmiBroker DateTime object into UInt64
    /// </summary>
    static ulong PackDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return PackDate(date, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pack AmiBroker DateTime object into UInt64
    /// </summary>
    static ulong PackDate(DateTime date, bool isFeaturePad)
    {
        var isEOD = date.Hour == 0 && date.Minute == 0 && date.Second == 0;

        // lower 32 bits
        var ft = BitVector32.CreateSection(1);
        var rs = BitVector32.CreateSection(23, ft);
        var ms = BitVector32.CreateSection(999, rs);
        var ml = BitVector32.CreateSection(999, ms);
        var sc = BitVector32.CreateSection(59, ml);

        var bv1 = new BitVector32(0);
        bv1[ft] = isFeaturePad ? 1 : 0;         // bit marking "future data"
        bv1[rs] = 0;                            // reserved set to zero
        bv1[ms] = 0;                            // microseconds 0..999
        bv1[ml] = date.Millisecond;             // milliseconds 0..999
        bv1[sc] = date.Second;                  // 0..59

        // higher 32 bits
        var mi = BitVector32.CreateSection(59);
        var hr = BitVector32.CreateSection(23, mi);
        var dy = BitVector32.CreateSection(31, hr);
        var mn = BitVector32.CreateSection(12, dy);
        var yr = BitVector32.CreateSection(4095, mn);

        var bv2 = new BitVector32(0);
        bv2[mi] = isEOD ? 63 : date.Minute;     // 0..59        63 is reserved as EOD marker
        bv2[hr] = isEOD ? 31 : date.Hour;       // 0..23        31 is reserved as EOD marker
        bv2[dy] = date.Day;                     // 1..31
        bv2[mn] = date.Month;                   // 1..12
        bv2[yr] = date.Year;                    // 0..4095

        return ((ulong)bv2.Data << 32) ^ (ulong)bv1.Data;
    }
```

What I'd like to know is, is my understanding of the PackDate function correct?  That is, am I putting the right input into it?  Or is there something wrong with the way I'm reading and parsing the text file?  Those are the two places I suspect I'm going wrong.  I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to `PackDate` - all 32 bits of `bv1` are used to store the time, and casting the integer value in `bv1.Data` straight to a `ulong` is causing an overflow when the first bit of `bv1` is populated, due to fact that the MSB of an int is used for the sign.

Here's what `PackDate` encodes into bv1:

```
Name | Max size (decimal) | Bits required
ft   |   1                |  1
rs   |  23                |  5
ms   | 999                | 10
ml   | 999                | 10
sc   |  59                |  6
====================================
TOTAL                       32
```

Since the "seconds" field occupies the most significant bits, the overflow happens for any date where the number of seconds is more than 31.

To prevent the overflow, the last line of `PackDate` needs to be changed to this:

```
return ((ulong)(uint)bv2.Data << 32) ^ (uint)bv1.Data;
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so much! You've helped me so much!  It worked.  I tried to mark it up, apparently I don't have enough reputation to do so +1000.

Comment: No worries, @user1581495. It was a good question! Even if you don't have the reputation to upvote, you can still mark my answer as the [accepted answer](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)...

Comment: Can you suggest how to "UnPack" the same ? i.e. ulong to DateTime ?

Comment: Hi @Nikki, you can use `BitVector32` to unpack too - just create sections as per the question and read out their values instead of writing to them.